# Detecting VPN connection

Tags: javascript, vpn

Is it possible to check if a user is connected to a VPN and retrieve internal IP address through Javascript?

Comment: If you mean from JavaScript in a web browser, then I would seriously doubt it; the browser itself probably doesn't know (depending on the nature of the VPN).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462925/how-to-test-if-an-employee-is-connected-via-vpn-with-client-side-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can't check for VPN usage nor get the IP address of a user with just JavaScript in the browser.

Your best bet would be to look for VPN IP blacklists to integrate with your server configuration, these will block most free VPNs and some paid ones but the paid ones will always keep expanding their IP address base.

There are paid lists which will be more accurate, but there are also some daily-updated open source projects, like these:

- https://github.com/X4BNet/lists_vpn/blob/main/output/vpn/ipv4.txt
- https://github.com/X4BNet/lists_vpn/blob/main/output/datacenter/ipv4.txt (datacenters)
- https://github.com/stamparm/ipsum/blob/master/ipsum.txt (bots)
- https://github.com/josephrocca/is-vpn/blob/main/vpn-or-datacenter-ipv4-ranges.txt
- https://github.com/X4BNet/lists_torexit/blob/main/ipv4.txt (TOR nodes - note that Cloudflare allows detecting TOR on free plan)

You'll need to test this data to see if it's accurate enough for your use case.

And note that if you block VPNs, you will restrict some users that only have access to your website via a VPN service for privacy reasons. There are legitimate and important reasons for users to have a VPN.

---

The WebRTC leak doesn't work anymore on most (all?) modern browsers, and VPN browser extensions tend to patch it anyway.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see this repo https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips.
it won't get block by browser plugins. But the user can disable webrtc

EDIT:

From: http://thehackernews.com/2015/02/webrtc-leaks-vpn-ip-address.html

> HOW DOES THE WebRTC FLAW WORK
>   WebRTC allows requests to be made to STUN (Session Traversal Utilities for NAT) servers which return the "hidden" home IP-address as well as local network addresses for the system that is being used by the user.
>
> The results of the requests can be accessed using JavaScript, but because they are made outside the normal XML/HTTP request procedure, they are not visible in the developer console. This means that the only requirement for this to work is WebRTC support in the browser and JavaScript.

Comment: Could you please explain (expanding your answer) *why* you think webrtc might be an option? In my mind I'm thinking: vpn-router.. no way, vpn-tap-driver (properly setup) no way, just the browser tunneled over vpn... maybe. What will happen with the old java-applet trick that 'silently' fetched the ip addres.. no idea.

Comment: e... my english is poor... you can see these two links http://thehackernews.com/2015/02/webrtc-leaks-vpn-ip-address.html and https://torrentfreak.com/huge-security-flaw-leaks-vpn-users-real-ip-addresses-150130/

Comment: I took the liberty of adding this into your answer (since the PoC code mentioned here http://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/2cfg84/all_vpn_anonymity_destroyed_in_3_min_with/ is offline and unknown to me how that worked). On a related side-note, I really hope this WebRTC gets fixed soon as it appears that currently one can only disable webrtc and or javascript to protect against this attack.

Comment: i fail to see how this answer is relevant, making a move like this based on a leak will bring your website popularity to the ground.