# Is there a way to check if a user can resolve a certain hostname using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, networking, dns, frontend

I'm developing an internal VueJS app and I'd like some links to be only accessible if the user is connected to the corporate VPN. Since you can't reliably get the user local IP address via WebRTC, I've thought about checking if the user can perform a DNS lookup against a host that only exists inside the company network. If the DNS resolution works, it means that the user is connected to the VPN.

So, is there a pure JS (frontend only) way to check if a user can resolve a hostname?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-think how you check if the user is connected to a VPN.
DNS resolution is very easily bypassed on the client side.

Maybe you could check it by invoking a simple service within your corporate network.

EDIT: A while ago there was a very similar problem with a simple example of a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462925/how-to-test-if-an-employee-is-connected-via-vpn-with-client-side-javascript)